# Possible Google Analytics Bug - Traffic Sources Total Visits not matching Total Visits in other reports

Tags: google-analytics

Has anyone else seen this issue?

As of roughly 2 weeks ago, I get conflicting figures for the Total Visits metric between the Traffic Sources report and the other reports (e.g. Visitors, Dashboard). For example, for the week of 5/9/2010 through 5/15/2010, the Dashboard and Visitors reports both say 386 Visits. The Traffic Sources report says 157 Visits, and the 4 main source types (Search, Direct, Referral, Other) sum to 157 Visits, not 386.

Any ideas? Is this a known bug, or could there be a configuration issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This is clearly programming related; it's just domain-specific and so the connection just isn't obvious. For instance, while the question doesn't contain code, the data recited there were created by code, and the most useful answers will likely be in the form of code (e.g., a regular expression filter or javascript snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that quite a few GA users have observed unaccounted-for behavior, particularly during the past couple of months.

For instance,

**18 - 19 May 2010**:

> more than ***40*** different GA users posted to the GA
>   User Forum all regarding the same
>   [issue](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/label?lid=55b995552f657452&hl=en): no data whatever was
>   recorded in their GA Accounts
>   during the 18th and 19th of May. No
>   response from Google and nothing in
>   the GA Blog. Several users who had
>   other GA accounts that were functioning normally during this period, suggested that the problem might be caused by recent changes by  Google to the GATC (which was in fact recently revised)--many of those who posted on the Forum said that indeed they had recently added the latest version of the GATC to their Sites/Pages.

**6 - 9 May 2010**:

> Over 50 GA users reported, [by
>   posts](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=5f70904f5fd49cf5&hl=en&start=40) to the GA Forum, a complete
>   GA outage during the period 6 - 9 May
>   (no data appearing in their reports
>   for at least one of those days). This
>   time a GA Team member did respond with
>   a [one-line response](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=5f70904f5fd49cf5&hl=en&start=40) "there was a
>   delay in reporting, no data was lost."
>   This post also referenced a Twitter
>   message [4](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=075a1ec904f139b9&hl=en) from GA stating the same
>   thing.

In addition, i've seen a half dozen, perhaps more, recent posts (past 60 days) on the GA Forum in which users reported significant discrepancies between an aggregate figure and the sum of the constituents--both sets of figures from the *same* Report, e.g.,

*[Numbers Don't add up on the Absolute Unique Visitor's Report](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=075a1ec904f139b9&hl=en)*

*[Search Engine drill-down visitors don't match total](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=161afeb095fcc84f&hl=en)*

Neither Post was answered (either by the GA Team or anyone else).

Finally, since it's just a matter of clicking a menu and selecting a different option, i suggest comparing the figures you recited in your question with the analogous figures for ***Page Views***, which is probably the simplest measurement in client-side analytics ("Visits" by contrast is strongly influenced by user cookie manipulation).

Comment: Thanks, Doug, for your reply. Through trial-and-error I think I've uncovered the issue. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial-and-error looking at every specific source, I've traced the error to one item: within the Traffic Sources reports for the affected days (the issue seems to have partially righted itself as of yesterday's data, at least for my account), the delta/error/black hole was always equal to the Google CPC Search traffic for that day.

I have no idea what's causing the issue, but at least I know how to manually attribute the numbers. Hopefully Google has fixed this...

Thank you to all who commented/answered. I appreciate it.